# Inverter using Wien Oscillator

Tags: oscillator

Here is Wien Oscillator circuit:

[image]

Amplitude of oscillations, Vout, is about 10V. If I put step up transformer on output with appropriate primary/secondary ratio, I can get 220V AC voltage, and it would be some basic DC to AC inverter, right? But because of small output current of LM741, it can't be used to power bulb for example?

Comment: Right, and right again. Note that if you step voltage up 20:1 you also step current down 20:1, so if the 741 can supply 20mA (optimistic) you could expect 1mA at 220V which is practically useless.

Comment: NO, just slapping an oscillator and a transformer together does not make a DC to 220V AC inverter that can power a lightbulb. Have a look at some of the many schematics you find if you google on: "power inverter schematic" and then select "images" (instead of websites). Note how the circuit that drives the step up transformer is never just a 741 opamp.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I don't want to use this circuit as DC to AC inverter. I'm studying oscillator circuits and I came up with idea to connect transformer to get some basic inverter, only for experiment purposes.

Comment: Right. Power, not voltage or current, is conserved. So a +/- 10 volt output is about 7 volts RMS. A 741 can put out about 10 mA. Power available is then 7 x .01, or 70 mW. So, well, you _can_ drive a light bulb - as long as it's a 70 mW bulb, and those are hard to find.

Comment: Like using a candle to boil a kettle.

Comment: Regarding the headline: Where do you see an "inverter"? The WIEN oscillator needs a minimum gain of +3 (1+22/10=3.2)..

Comment: The oscillator Generates the Sine wave, so you can feed it to a power amplifier & then connect that to the Transformer to get a high power output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very impractical.

1) The sinusoidal signal generated is not efficient for power generation -- because it uses a linear amplifier to convert the supply power to the sinusoid.

2) A light bulb would be perfectly happy with a square wave, and this can be generated much more efficiently.